# ¿Como se usa el self?

Tags: python

hace poco me cambie de versión de `python`, tenia la `3.9.2` y ahora tengo la `3.9.5`; vi como en los códigos de POO que tengo marcan errores, y me di cuenta de dos cosas, 1: ahora se le debe pasar como atributo a los métodos/comportamientos el objeto perteneciente a la clase es decir el `self`, 2: antes si querías acceder a una variable perteneciente al objeto de la clase (ejemplo: `self.dinero`), solo tenias que hacer esto:

```
class persona():
def __init__(self):
    self.dinero = 10

obj = persona
print(obj.dinero)
```

Pero actualmente esto ocasiona este error: `AttributeError: type object 'persona' has no attribute 'dinero'`

¿Cual es la forma nueva de hacerlo, o me estoy simplemente equivocando y siempre a estado mal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Causa: Faltan los paréntesis en la invocación de `persona`.

Solución:

```
class persona:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dinero = 10

objeto = persona()
print(objeto.dinero) => 10
```

Para crear un objeto de una cierta clase, tienes que ocupar el nombre de la clase seguido de `()`. Eso instancia un objeto.

Si usas el nombre sin los paréntesis, te estas refiriendo a la clase, no a un objeto en particular.

Comment: JAJAJ diosss, que estupidez era, muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo :33